# How to log in to account on startup?

Tags: windows, boot

I have 2 accounts.  How would I go about automatically logging in to one of the accounts when I start the computer up?  So, it would not give the user the option to log into the other account right off the bat.

Would I use a batch file and use Group Policy to run it?  If so, what command is used to log in from a batch file?

Comment: I was going to post it there, but my question is more programming-related.

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows-7/99d4fe75-3f22-499b-85fc-c7a2c4f728af

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you, but I really need a way to do it via a startup script, as I only want it to automatically log in if the screen resolution is 1920x1080, which requires a startup script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
set LOGON_KEY=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

rem check screen resolution here, if check succeeds:
rem set RESOLUTION_OK=y

if /i "%RESOLUTION_OK%"=="y" (
  reg add "%LOGON_KEY%" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 1
  reg add "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultUserName /t REG_SZ /d USER
  reg add "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultDomainName /t REG_SZ /d DOMAIN
  reg add "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultPassword /t REG_SZ /d PASS
) else (
  reg add "%LOGON_KEY%" /v AutoAdminLogon /t REG_SZ /d 0
  reg delete "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultUserName
  reg delete "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultDomainName
  reg delete "%LOGON_KEY%" /v DefaultPassword
)
```

It should enable auto-logon for DOMAIN\USER with the password PASS. To avoid storing credentials in a script, you could manually create and populate the values `DefaultUserName`, `DefaultDomainName` and `DefaultPassword`, and only toggle the `AutoAdminLogon` value.